# pass paramater to useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get id of the current rendered item(in my case topic).I'm trying to do it via useEffect() hook but it seems it can not accept paramaters.
Is there any way to fix it and pass recieved data to other elements?

Here is the full functional component of mine :

```
    const PostOnPage: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  // Dont let in without token
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:4000/`, {
        headers: {
          "auth-token": localStorage.getItem("auth-token"),
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("--------res.data", res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
        toast.info("You must Log In");
        history.push("/login");
      });
  }, []);

  //Get Post By Id
 useEffect((id : Number) => {
     axios
         .get(`http://localhost:4000/getTopic/${id}`)
         .then((post) => {
           console.log('--------post.data', post.data.description);
         })
         .catch((err)=>{
           console.log('--------err', err);
         })
 })

  const LogOut = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    history.push("/login");
  };

  const history = useHistory();
  let posts: any = useSelector((state: any) => state.posts);

  return (
    <div id="card" className="card">
      <div id="postButtons" className="buttons">
        <button onClick={() => history.push("/homepage")}>Home</button>
        <button onClick={() => history.push("/profile")}>My Profile</button>
        <button onClick={() => LogOut()}>Log Out</button>
      </div>
      <div className="posts">
        <p>
          Title :
          {posts.map((title: any) => {
            return title.title;
          })}
        </p>

        <p>
          Description :
          {posts.map((item : any) => {return getPostById(item.id)})}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostOnPage;
```

Comment: You can get this id from the current component if it has one. Can you show us the component where you use useEffect?

Comment: Yes I will update the post

Comment: I updated it !!

Comment: Thanks. But there is no id defined or passed in there, where would you be getting it from?

Comment: I render this component from another component after a click on the title,and i want id to generate after this component is rendered

Comment: i thought useEffect would do the thing

Comment: You should [read the docs on useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). But in any case, no one is going to generate the id for you, you have to get it from somewhere or generate yourself, and then pass it to the components that need it.

Comment: So in my case i shall pass it from another component as props

Answer (score 4):

useEffect hook is used to execute functionality according to data change / onload.
It can't receive parameters,
If you want to use the id of your current render in your useEffect you should send him as prop.

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` hook doesn't take a parameter. You have to pass the parameter in the component.

```
const Component = ({ id }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:4000/getTopic/${id}`)
            .then((post) => {
                console.log('--------post.data', post.data.description);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('--------err', err);
            })
    })

    return (
         // your render
          )
}
```

Comment: Can i pass props from another component ?

Comment: in functional component

Comment: Yes. You have to pass the id from parent component like this `<Component id= {id}/>`

Comment: I tried to do it from another functional component but it's letting me do it

Comment: Could you please share your parent component in which u are using `PostOnPage` component.

Answer (score 1):

if you store Id in state then you can trigger useEffect if id is change.
in below example I stored id in state and us it to in second useEffect function. you also need to add change parameter of useEffect

```
 const PostOnPage: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [id,setId]=useState()
  // Dont let in without token
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:4000/`, {
        headers: {
          "auth-token": localStorage.getItem("auth-token"),
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setId(res.data.id)
        console.log("--------res.data", res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
        toast.info("You must Log In");
        history.push("/login");
      });
  }, []);

  //Get Post By Id
 useEffect(() => {
     axios
         .get(`http://localhost:4000/getTopic/${id}`)
         .then((post) => {
           console.log('--------post.data', post.data.description);
         })
         .catch((err)=>{
           console.log('--------err', err);
         })
 },[id])

  const LogOut = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    history.push("/login");
  };

  const history = useHistory();
  let posts: any = useSelector((state: any) => state.posts);

  return (
    <div id="card" className="card">
      <div id="postButtons" className="buttons">
        <button onClick={() => history.push("/homepage")}>Home</button>
        <button onClick={() => history.push("/profile")}>My Profile</button>
        <button onClick={() => LogOut()}>Log Out</button>
      </div>
      <div className="posts">
        <p>
          Title :
          {posts.map((title: any) => {
            return title.title;
          })}
        </p>

        <p>
          Description :
          {posts.map((item : any) => {return getPostById(item.id)})}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostOnPage;
```